# Calling ViewController class methods in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Quick question, Imagine me having two ViewControllers, in one of them, I have a written a method that loads data from an API an stores it inside a global array.

Is it a good idea to call that method from THE OTHER ViewController by doing this?:

```
MyDataLoadingVC().loadData()
```

Here I create another instance of the `MyDataLoadingViewController` class, and call the method on that instance. I'm thinking, since the method does not have any effect on the instance on which it is being called (in the case of this method it doesn't, I'm sure), this is ok, right?. 
I have never seen someone do it and it seems okay to me, what do you think?

Thx in advance!

Comment: It's a bad idea to load data in `UIViewController` overall; you should create some DataManager class to do that.

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, fixed it.

I made a special data managing class with all the data-fetching methods in it. This works fine!